# Persistence Injection fails, NPE

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, tomcat7

I'm trying to inject an EntityManager into my Tomcat 7 application.

I have a class that manages my queries (service.PresentatieDao), in which I have this code:

```
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have this line:

```
<bean name = "presentatieDao" class="service.PresentatieDao"/>
```

And finally in my dispatcher-servlet.xml I have this code (copy paste with edits to point correctly):

```
<bean id="messageSource" 
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basename="messages" />

<bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" 
              value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" 
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Project2-DB"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>domein</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" /> 
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" 
      class=" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager ">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

And in my controller:

```
@Autowired
private PresentatieDao presentatieDao;
```

I have gotten all types of errors about my mapping, which I have solved.

Now I get a NullPointerException at this line in my PresentatieDao:

```
return em.createQuery("select p from Presentatie p").getResultList();
```

the em is `null` in this case. Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Comment: do you have package **domein** or **service**

Comment: Yes domein contains all my entities and service contains my DAO class

Comment: you have mixed up spring annotation and xml bean declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i checked Spring docummentation.It should work like this

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" />

<bean name = "presentatieDao" class="service.PresentatieDaoImpl"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

and

```
public class PresentatieDaoImpl implements PresentatieDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this. entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Collection loadProductsByCategory(String category) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Product p where p.category = :category")
            .setParameter("category", category).getResultList();
    }
}
```

for more:

https://spring.io/blog/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring

you can also check:

http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/spring-persistencecontext-explained/

Comment: Now I'm getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [service.PresentatieDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: and when I add the bean, I get the same NPE

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I tried it on my other pc, it just worked... Maybe something in my config, java installation, tomcat installation that went wrong, no clue. Your answer is right though.